# error on my first Sqoop job.

Tags: mysql, hadoop, jdbc, import, sqoop

this is the command i am executing.

```
 $ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopguide --table widgets -m 1
```

the error->>

```
$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopguide --table widgets -m 1
Warning: /media/akshay/MyMedia/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-1.0.0/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /media/akshay/MyMedia/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-1.0.0/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /media/akshay/MyMedia/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-1.0.0/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
16/05/20 14:08:06 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
16/05/20 14:08:06 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
16/05/20 14:08:06 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/05/20 14:08:06 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `widgets` AS t LIMIT 1
16/05/20 14:08:06 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error reading from database: java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@1d296da is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
java.sql.SQLException: Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@1d296da is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:931)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkForOutstandingStreamingData(MysqlIO.java:2518)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1748)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1961)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2537)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2466)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getMaxBytesPerChar(ConnectionImpl.java:2939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Field.getMaxBytesPerCharacter(Field.java:576)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.getPrecision(ResultSetMetaData.java:440)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:286)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
16/05/20 14:08:06 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:107)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

i've read somewhere that warnings are harmless.

also when i am executing this command i am getting the output

```
$ sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopguide
```

the output ->

```
Warning: /media/akshay/MyMedia/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-1.0.0/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /media/akshay/MyMedia/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-1.0.0/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /media/akshay/MyMedia/sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-1.0.0/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
16/05/20 14:10:32 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
16/05/20 14:10:32 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
widgets
```

please provide some help/suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to specify following arguments:

The HDFS directory where to import your data:

```
--target-dir $hdfs_path
```

If your Mysql Database needs a username and a password:

```
--username $user --password $pass
```

If you haven't done this yet, provide a port number to your MySQL Path:

```
jdbc:mysql://$server:$port/$database
```

This should help!

Answer (score 0):

@akshay naidu: It seems that the mysql connector version is not the latest which you are using.Check the below jira link:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1400

Upgrade your connector and then try.

Comment: it was the latest one